# Ckeditor responsive images and responsive tables

Tags: django, responsive-design, ckeditor, responsive-images

I'm using ckeditor in my django project. It's a responsive page hence everything changes when the width of the page changes except for tables and images, they remain the same size.
I'm using 'safe' filter to render everything, it works fine, but the images and tables do not resize.
How do I make them responsive for different screens sizes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using bootstrap on front?

Comment: Yes @PasqualGuerrero

Comment: You could try this.. http://ckeditor.com/addon/bootstrapVisibility to add bootstrap classes on rendered images

Comment: But I just use "content|safe" filter to render stuff. I tried to put it in a class of "img-responsive" but it didn't resize the image or the table @PasqualGuerrero